# Smart contract deploy with hardhat and heroku - ERR hardhat not installed

Tags: node.js, heroku, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a `nodejs` server running on `heroku` and I want my users to be able to deploy `smart-contracts` from the frontend of the app, which makes `api` calls to the server.

The problem:

I initialized the project with `npx hardhat init`, added my server things and tested everything locally. It works flawlessly, but on `heroku` I keep getting: `hardhat not installed`, even though it is added to `package.json`.

I tried many things for many hours. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: `hardhat` was in `devDep.` and should have been in `dependencies`.

Comment: is your hardhat a standalone node app? I am looking for bundling node express app with hardhat and then use the etherjs methods from the router methods. Let me know if you have something for me.

Comment: yes it is. You need to be more specific if you have a question